# Crashlytics, the number of affected users in dashboard doesn't make sense

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

We have Crashlytics in an Android project. According to the dashboard we observe crashes which happen thousand of times for very low number of users, that seems not logically for me, it's hard to imagine that a user can get 500 crashes, before he decides to throw it all away.

What could be reasons for having such a report.
Base on the Crashlytics model as long as user doesn't uninstall an App, he is treated as one single user.

Any thoughts

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say anything on this without knowing the exact number of crashes and users. Also, what kind of a crash they're running into plays an important role here. For the most part, it is very unlikely that multiple reports are being posted for a single crash. As soon as a crash report is sent successfully, the report is deleted from the device.